# AJAX-requests do not work/get blocked because of CORS-issues

Tags: shopware, shopware6

we recently encountered a problem with the shopware storefront watcher, where AJAX-requests do not work/get blocked because of CORS-issues.
Example from `views/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig`:

```
{% set config = {
    url: url('frontend.detail.switch', { productId: page.product.parentId })
} %}
```

The url generated doesn't contain the watcher-port, so the request essentially goes to another host (the one without the port) and therefore is cross origin.

Has anyone encountered this before and maybe solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this issue. The twig url function calls the router with the `UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL` type. The router then uses the current request context to build the URL with scheme, host and port. Unfortunately that request context will have used the default port `80` as it is not the port of the hot proxy that would've been resolved from the current request. So it seems to be a general issue when generating absolute URLs and using them with the hot proxy.

Unfortunately I couldn't come up with a quick, revertible solution either. Using `path` instead of `url` seemed to work without issue but still requires changes in the template:

```
{% set config = {
    url: path('frontend.detail.switch', { productId: page.product.parentId })
} %}
```

Comment: That's good news that this is not only us, should I create a GitHub issue for that?
In other places in the template there is a check if the current "mode" is hot reloading, maybe this check could also be made in the places where this occurs. Or the url-twig function has to be overwritten or something like that...

Comment: Please create a ticket on the [issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com/).

Comment: For reference: the ticket is created here https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-23561